# how to get url parameter in modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I have one model name is cityform

i want to get url parmeter in this CityFrom hwo can i do this?

here is my url

```
path('state/city/<int:id>/', City.as_view(), name="city")
```

http://localhost:8000/country/state/city/3/

here is my form

class

```
CityFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(CityFrom,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)

        self.fields['state'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                 empty_label = 'Select',
                                 queryset = State.objects.all()
                                ) 
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('state', 'name')
```

in this form i want to access id  = 3

here is my view

```
from django.views import View
class City(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Forms = CityFrom()
        return render(request, 'albums/add.html', {'Forms': Forms})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass url parameter as keyword argument from views.py as following.

```
form = CityFrom(id=kwargs.get("id"))
```

To get the id in your forms.py, use following code in your form's `__init__` method.

```
self.id = kwargs.get('id')
```

Your form should look like this.

```
CityFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.get('id')

        super(CityFrom,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['state'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                 empty_label = 'Select',
                                 queryset = State.objects.all()
                                ) 
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('state', 'name')
```

* Call super after getting the id in your form as above. Here order of calling super is important.

Comment: @lijharul Islam ji not working dear "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
"

Comment: Forms = CityFrom(id=kwargs.get("id")) i did this and in from i am printing this dear print(kwargs )

Comment: I am geting id in view with the help of kwargs.get('id')

Comment: but unable to get in model form class

Comment: I updated the answer. Have a look. hope it will help.

Comment: Where does the line "form = CityFrom(id=kwargs.get("id"))" go?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CityFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(CityFrom,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```